# Python ExchangeLib Update Calendar Item reminder_is_set

Tags: python, exchangelib

All,

I am new to Python, and I am having issues updating the `reminder_is_set` property on calendar items. I am trying to get my calendar items from now and 7 days ahead and turn off the reminders.

I can get the calendar items in the view just fine. I can enumerate the items just fine. I just can't seem to figure out how to update the value and save each item. I looked at the examples and see the bulk update sample, but I don't see where the value is being set between the fetch and the bulk update call. Any and all help appreciated.

```
calendar_items = account.calendar.view(start=startDate, end=currentDateTime)

calendar_ids = [(i.id, i.changekey) for i in calendar_items]

items_iter = account.fetch(ids=calendar_ids, only_fields='reminder_is_set')
for item in items_iter:
    item.reminder_is_set = False

updated_ids = account.bulk_update(items=[(i, ('reminder_is_set')) for i in calendar_items])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your changes are in `items_iter` but you are calling `bulk_update()` with `calendar_items` which doesn't have the changes.

Here's an example that should work:

```
update_pairs = []
for item in account.calendar\
        .view(start=startDate, end=currentDateTime)\
        .only('reminder_is_set'):
    if item.reminder_is_set:
        item.reminder_is_set = False
        update_pairs.append((item, ('reminder_is_set',)))

updated_ids = account.bulk_update(items=update_pairs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Erik. Appreciate it.